# Как на wordpress сделать проверку сложности пароля?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю кастомную форму регистрации на wordpress. Все замечательно работает, проверка на php (чтоб логин не повторялся), валидация на js и данные заносятся в БД. Как сделать проверку сложности пароля, как при регистрации пользователей из админки?

my_temp_page.php:

```
<form class="form-container recall-form-validate" id="form_id">

  <div class="form-title">Введите Ваше имя <span>*</span>:</div>
  <input class="form-field form-name " id="name" type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Введите имя"/><br />


  <div class="form-title">Пароль <span>*</span>:</div>
  <input class="form-field form-password" type="password" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="Введите пароль"/><br />

  <div class="form-title">Пароль еще раз:</div>
  <input class="form-field form-password" type="password"  id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Введите снова пароль"/><br />

  <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
  <h1><div id="info_field" class="submit-container"></div></h1>
</form>
```

functions.js:

```
jQuery(".submit-button").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        var name = jQuery(".form-name").val();
        var password1 = jQuery("#password1").val();
        var password2 = jQuery("#password2").val();

    if(name == '') {
        document.getElementById('name').classList.add("false_validation");
    }
    if(password1 == ''){
        document.getElementById('password1').classList.add("false_validation");
    }
    if(password2 == ''){
        document.getElementById('password2').classList.add("false_validation");
    }
    if(password1 !== password2){
        document.getElementById('password1').classList.add("false_validation");
        document.getElementById('password2').classList.add("false_validation");
        jQuery('#info_field').html('Пароли не совпадают!');
    }

}
```

functions.php:

```
function ab_create_new_user() {
$userdata = array (
    'first_name' => $_POST['name'],
    'user_pass'  => $_POST['password1'],
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
if( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo $user_id->get_error_message(); /*'false';*/
}
exit();
}
```

Comment: Гугл выдал ссылку на это руководство: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-the-included-password-strength-meter-script-in-wordpress--wp-34736 .
Если ещё не пробовали, то, возможно, поможет.

А вообще, WordPress, вроде как, используется библиотеку "zxcvbn" для проверки сложности пароля https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn .

Comment: @Денис Янчевский , да, спасибо, я уже знаком с этим руководством и подобными ему. Только вот не понял как в js может быть такая вот строка $submitButton.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );? Поэтому не смог реализовать по данному руководству.

Comment: @Александр Это код с jQuery.  $submitButton - Это переменная в которую передается название класса, id или тип кнопки, в примере это  кнопка: $('input[type=submit]'), // Submit button передается в функцию.  Далее  .attr() - Это работа с атрибутами.   'disabled'  это  атрибут  с параметром:  'disabled'  - Заблокированное в поле